# Unexpected behavior on adding '\0' to std::string

Tags: c++, string, stl

Why does the C++ standard allow the following?

```cxx
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    

int main()
{
    std::string s(10, '\0'); // s.length() now is 10
    std::cout << "string is " << s << ", length is " << s.length() << std::endl;
    s.append(5, '\0'); // s.length() now is 15 
    std::cout << "string is " << s << ", length is " << s.length() << std::endl;
    // the same with += char and push_back 

    // but:
    s += "hello"; // s.length() returns 20 string is "hello"
    std::cout << "string is " << s << ", length is " << s.length() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does it add 0 and count it?
It looks like broken integrity of string, doesn't it? But I checked standard and it is correct behavior.

Comment: `std::string` is not a null-terminated string.

Comment: "Broken integrity of string"? The whole point of `std::string` is that you are free of arbitrary restrictions from 1970 such as "cannot contain `\0`".

Comment: If you checked the standard and saw that this is correct behavior, what's your question?

Comment: Think of `std::string` as a kind of container of characters, with a bunch of character string functionality thrown in.

Comment: There is CharTraits::length and I think that length always should return value which is equal to this function value.

Comment: After the `+= "hello"` line, the string is NOT the 5-character string `"hello"`, as your comment implies.  The string is in fact `"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0hello"`, but your terminal probably can't print the ASCII NUL character, so it *appears* to only print `"hello"`.  But if you save your program's output to a file and examine the raw file data, you'll see the 15 NUL characters there.

Answer (score 8):

> Why does standard allows following?

Because the people designing C++ strings decided that such things should be allowed. I'm not sure if anyone that was part of the team that designed C++ strings are on SO... But since you yourself say that the standard allows it, that's the way it is, and I doubt it's about to change.

It's sometimes quite practical to have a string that can contain "anything". I can think of a few instances when I've had to work around the fact that C style strings can't contain zero-bytes. Along with the fact that long C style strings take a long time to find the length of, the main benefit of C++ strings is that they are not restricted to "what you can put in them" - that's a good thing in my book.

Comment: There's the added complication that `c_str()` does return a null-terminated string, which means that std::string implementations have to use both a length field *and* a null terminator.

Comment: @Roddy: Yes, and if you do stuff a zero in the middle, you clearly can't use it as a c_str() string in a conventional C style string way. You can't have the cake and eat it. Actually, UNTIL such a point that you call `c_str()`, I don't believe the implementation HAS to stuff a zero at the end. But I suspect most implementations do, simply because it's easier to do that than to reallocate the string and stuff a zero in there when you hit the `c_str()` - especially in C++ 11 where `c_str()` is defined to return the actual data from the string, not a secondary copy.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what is problem here.

Adding `'\0'` in the middle of the `std::string` changes nothing - null character is treated like any other. The only thing that can change is if you use `.c_str()` with function that accepts null-terminated strings. But then it's not problem of `.c_str()`, only with the function that treats `'\0'` specially.

If you want to know how many characters has this string as if treated like null-terminated string, use

```
size_t len = strlen(s.c_str());
```

Note that it's O(n) operation, because that's how `strlen` works.

If you ask why `+=` operator doesn't add the implicit null character of string literal `"hello"` to the string, I say the reverse (adding it) is unclear and definitely not what you want 99% of the time. On the other hand, if you want to add `'\0'` to your string, just append it like a buffer:

```
char buffer[] = "Hello";
s.append(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

or (even better) drop the char arrays and null-terminated strings altogether and use C++-style replacements like `std::string` as NTS-replacement, `std::vector<char>` as contiguous buffer, `std::vector` as dynamic array with pointers replacement, and `std::array` (C++11) as standard C array replacement.

Also, (as mentioned by @AdamRosenfield in comments), your string after adding `"hello"` does have in fact 20 characters, it's probably only that your terminal doesn't print nulls.

Answer (score 2):

`NUL` char `'\0'` is the ending character for `c style string`, not `std::string`s. However, it supports this character to get values from a const char pointer so that it can find the end of a c-style string. Otherwise, it is treated just like other characters

Answer (score 1):

std::string is more of a container for characters than anything else and \0 is a character. As a real world example, take a look at the [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in Windows. The lpEnvironment parameter takes a null-terminated block of null-terminated strings (i.e. `A=1\0B=2\0C=3\0\0`). If you're building a block it's convenient to use an std::string.